# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.SdkReference' on project open in VS 2017 U1 (15.3)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

After doing an (apparently successful) upgrade from VS 2017 15.1 to 15.3, I can no longer load any C# project (can't open existing, can't create new). All fail with this error:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.SdkReference' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I found one reference to someone running into this problem with an RC version of 15.3, but no others, so I've got no idea what about my environment might be causing this problem. I've tried clearing cache and user data, repair, complete uninstall/reinstall, and removing 3rd party components. I am out of ideas.

There's absolutely tons of info I could provide here, so I'm not sure where to start. I'm grateful for any ideas or at least to see if others are running into the same problem.

Comment: I have found [something](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94979/cannot-open-any-projects-in-solution-after-install.html). Did you try this solution?

Comment: Awesome find! I must have just missed that in my searches of that forum. I will try that. I downgraded back to 15.1 to get work done, but will test this. If it ends up being the solution, I'll let you know and you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @ViktorOleksyshyn - That was indeed the fix to the problem. Feel free to post an answer and I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: [This solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94979/cannot-open-any-projects-in-solution-after-install.html) could help (based on comment above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an adminstrator "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" to run

```
gacutil /u "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1"
```

Please do *not* reinstall another version to the GAC. MSBuild should not be in the GAC, and installing it there will cause problems the next time Visual Studio updates MSBuild, because the file from the GAC gets preferred over the updated version delivered with Visual Studio.

Comment: I knew something wasn't right when I had to do the previously-accepted answer every time I upgraded visual studio. I wonder how that assembly got into the GAC in the first place. Thanks for following up on this, Rainer.

Comment: Just a small addition: It also happens for VS 2019, and you can open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" - in my case it only worked when opened `as administrator`.

Comment: So installing 15.1 into the GAC fixed my issue. In my case it wasn't in the GAC, but I *did* have 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, and 14.0 in the GAC and I don't remember ever having registered those. The presence of the others was causing it to load the wrong one. Should I uninstall all of the other versions? Makes me wonder why they were there in the first place.

Answer (score 17):

1.- Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 as Admin

2.- Uninstall the Microsoft.Build.Framework from GAC (Global Assembly Cache)

```
gacutil /u Microsoft.Build.Framework
```

3.- Re-install the 15.1.0 version (correct path according to current VS2017 edition)

```
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll"
```

Now the projects in solutions should load properly.

Comment: Worked for me, changed path as I use 'Community' - many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue after installing Visual Studio 2015 on a machine that already had Visual Studio 2017.

Re-installing Microsoft.Build.Framework into the GAC solve my issue.