# Visual studio create project - could not load assembly Microsoft.Build.Framework

Tags: visual-studio

I update my Visual studio yesterday. Now I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Version 15.6.0 and I dont have create all projects. When I try create WPF project, it displayed this message:
[image]

When I try create other project, it displayed this message:
[image]

I tried repair and reinstall Visual Studio. 
Do you have any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002552/6157936) is solution.

open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 (I opened it as admin)

```
gacutil /u Microsoft.Build.Framework
```